# Once app is closed and open the ionic slider images are not displaying unless I move to next page

Tags: angular, ionic3

//// Where I get the data

```
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
  let record: any = {};
  record.slide = res.item(i).slide;
  records.push(record);
}

this.productsService.setslidesList = records;
setTimeout(() => {
  this.slider_img = records;
  console.log(this.slider_img)
  this.errInfo = false;
}, 300)
```

/// It displays error image unless If I redirect to another page starts working fine.

Comment: What if you refresh the page ? does it work well?

Comment: Yes it does but it is a Ionic mobile app reloading the page one more time making the UX bad

Comment: I will provide an answer to reload the page single time, which solved my issue when I faced the similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
       function reloadPage() {
            var currentDocumentTimestamp = new Date(performance.timing.domLoading).getTime();
            // Current Time //
            var now = Date.now();
            // Total Process Lenght as Minutes //
            var tenSec = 10 * 1000;
            // End Time of Process //
            var plusTenSec = currentDocumentTimestamp + tenSec;
            if (now > plusTenSec) {
                location.reload();
            }
        }
```

Try this, it reloads page single time, I know it is not best solution but, it helps in critical situations.